# How do i get Cosine Product approximation to work in Racket?

Tags: racket

For homework, I have to write a function which presents a product approximation of the cosine function which recurses until the difference between the current and newly calculated product is less than a threshold.

```lisp
(define (p_cos x)
(let* ([n 1]
       [xnew (* x (p_cos_aux x (+ n 1)))])
         (if (< (abs (- x xnew)) TOL)
             x
             (p_cos_aux xnew (+ n 1)))))

(define (p_cos_aux x n)
  (- 1 (/ (* 4 (square x)) (* (square pi) (square (- (* 2 n) 1))))))
```

the values are expected to be:

```
(p_cos 0)
=> 1
(p_cos (/ pi 2))
=> 0
```

however I am getting:

```
> (p_cos (/ pi 2))
0.9122085048010974
> (p_cos 0)
0
```

Can anyone explain to me why my outputs are so far from the expected values?

I'm basing my code off of this infinite product formula for approximations of cosine:

> cos(*x*) = ∏<sub>*n*=1</sub><sup>*n*→∞</sup> [ 1 − (4*x*<sup>2</sup>)/(π<sup>2</sup>(2*n* - 1)<sup>2</sup>) ]

Comment: Could you give the math formula that you're trying to implement? I'm not familiar with the cosine product approximation, and the only things I can find when I search for it are infinite sums or infinite products. Can you specify the formula, and if you're using only-the-first-n-terms of an infinite formula, could you show how you're using the formula off in math first?

Comment: the formula is the product series of (define (p_cos_aux x n)
  (- 1 (/ (* 4 (square x)) (* (square pi) (square (- (* 2 n) 1))))))

Comment: Can you show it as a "normal" math formula first, not just a racket one?

Comment: product (n = 1) n --> infinity (1 - (4x^2)/((pi^2)(2n - 1)^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're basing this on this math formula:

> cos(*x*) = ∏<sub>*n*=1</sub><sup>*n*→∞</sup> [ 1 − (4*x*<sup>2</sup>)/(π<sup>2</sup>(2*n* - 1)<sup>2</sup>) ]

It looks like your `p_cos_aux` function is handling the stuff inside the square brackets in the formula. So you still need to define cosine to be equal to

cos(*x*) = ∏<sub>*n*=1</sub><sup>*n*→∞</sup> `(p_cos_aux x n)`

If you want your code to return an answer, then you should to do this for only a finite number `n`. You can do this with either recursion or a for loop. In this case, Racket's [`for/product`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._for%2Fproduct))) loop is convenient:

```
(for/product ([n (in-range 1 ...some-large-number...)])
  (p_cos_aux x n))
```

Let's try putting in 100 for the large number:

```
(define (p_cos x)
  (for/product ([n (in-range 1 100)])
    (p_cos_aux x n)))
```

Trying it out:

```
> (p_cos 0)
1
> (p_cos (* 1/4 pi))
0.707553324600212
> (p_cos (* 1/2 pi))
0.0
> (p_cos (* 3/4 pi))
-0.7111358730792002
> (p_cos pi)
-1.01015228426396
> (p_cos (* 5/4 pi))
-0.7183556654338034
> (p_cos (* 3/2 pi))
-0.0
> (p_cos (* 7/4 pi))
0.7293234913165205
> (p_cos (* 2 pi))
1.0412338930105425
```

It's not perfect, but you can get better approximations by increasing the `100` to even larger numbers.